# If $f, \hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $f, \hat{f}\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for every $1 \geq p$

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis

My analysis reference claims quite casually that if $f, \hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $f$, then $f, \hat{f}\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for every $1 \geq p$. What I am wondering is that how could you prove the claim? It is not a given exercise or anything like that; that claim was dropped while the my reference goes over some general properties of Fourier transforms.

Where I am stuck, specifically, is that $$||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|^pdt = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(v)e^{-2\pi i t v}dv|^pdt\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(v)e^{-2\pi i t v}dv|^pdt\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\hat{f}(v)|^pdvdt$$

and it is quite hard to proceed beyond this point.

Comment: @kobe: not true unless $|f|\geq 1$

Comment: The statement as written by the OP is not true. Here is a counter example.
Let $f(x)=\frac12 e^{-|x|}$. Then $\widehat{f}(t)=\frac{1}{1+4\pi^2t^2}$.
Both $f,\widehat{f}\in L_1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ (here $\lambda$ Lebesgue's measure); however $\widehat{f}\notin L_p$ for $0<p<1$.
I believe that there was a typo in the reference that the OP is taking bout and that the author meant $p\geq1$

Comment: @OliverDíaz you are right, I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement as written by the OP is not true. Here is a counter example.
Let $f(x)=\frac12 e^{-|x|}$. Then $\widehat{f}(t)=\frac{1}{1+4\pi^2t^2}$.
Notice that both $f,\widehat{f}\in L_1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ (here $\lambda$ Lebesgue's measure); however $\widehat{f}\notin L_p$ for $0<p<1$.

I believe that there was a typo in the reference that the OP is taking bout and that the author meant $p\geq1$, for if $f,\widehat{f}\in L_1$, then from the Fourier inversion theorem it follows that $f$ (and $\widehat{f}$) is essentially an integrable continuous function that vanishes at infinity. This, for $p=1+\alpha$, $\alpha\geq0$
$$\int|f|^{1+\alpha}\,d\lambda\leq\|f\|^\alpha_\infty\|f\|_1<\infty$$
ans similarly for $\widehat{f}$.